# how to re add removed items from tool bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

i hav removed items from tool bar,but i want to re add it at particular time ...
how to do it..
i dont have images for them....

NSMutableArray *itemsToReplaceOldOnes=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.toolbar.items];
[itemsToReplaceOldOnes removeObjectAtIndex:2]; //remove UIBarButtonItems you want to remove
[self.toolbar setItems:itemsToReplaceOldOnes animated:YES];

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't just edit your question to be a completely different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from UIView, and so does not contain a `hidden` property. 
If you're using a UIToolbar use:

```
 NSMutableArray *itemsToReplaceOldOnes=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.toolbar.items];
[itemsToReplaceOldOnes removeObjectAtIndex:2]; //remove UIBarButtonItems you want to remove
[self.toolbar setItems:itemsToReplaceOldOnes animated:YES];
```

Comment: yes ,i have using same,but is showing request for member hidden is not a structure or union..

Comment: Ok, you could've specified that, 'is not working' isn't particularly useful. Could you maybe edit your question to show some code to see how you are using/accessing the UIButton?

Comment: I assume you have set a property for the UIToolbar. self.toolbar is just for example's sake

Comment: how to re add removed items from toolbar

Comment: I would recommend you don't hide the, just 'grey' them out, like so:         [self.toolbar.items objectAtIndex:1].enabled=NO;                    then re-enable them:                                [self.toolbar.items objectAtIndex:1].enabled=NO;